# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxxxx (wrong name: xxxxx) error when running program

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to run the code here -- http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowDownloadApps
--, and have this code in a Tester.java file (shown below). Two .jars are also in the same directory as this file, named androidmarketapi-0.6.jar and protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar. Both are in my classpath (I'm on Windows 7). It compiles fine, with the command "javac Tester.java". A Tester.class file is created in the same directory.

```
 public class Tester {
         public static void main (String[] args) {
                 MarketSession session = new MarketSession(true);
                         System.out.println("login...");
         }

 }
```

However, the program will not run!

```
 java Tester
```

and

```
 java -cp . Tester
```

both yield the below error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Tester
 (wrong name: com/gc/android/market/api/Tester)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
```

And there's 9~ more of these "at java.net", "at java.security", "at sun.misc,"
"at sun.launcher" type error messages.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include **androidmarketapi-0.6.jar and protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar** in CLASSPATH (cp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, I can see that Tester is inside a package `com.gc.android.market.api`

I would expect your console command to be something like

`java com.gc.android.market.api.Tester`